# ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver

Tags: java, spring, grails, jboss, wildfly

I am currently upgrading a grails app from grails 2.x to grails 4.

It is deployed on wildfly but for development i am using "grails run-app"

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver
```

Stack Trace:

```
2021-03-23 11:14:52.828 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /taskStatus/myTasks
org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/xml/JBossEntityResolver
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory.parse(WSDLDefinitionsFactory.java:104)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.ServiceMetaData.getWsdlDefinitions(ServiceMetaData.java:295)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.buildMetaData(JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.java:85)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.<init>(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:62)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:83)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:721)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.createJaxWsService(LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.java:169)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.prepare(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.ideas.cma.ws.JobTaskClient.getJobTaskList(JobTaskClient.java:20)
    at com.ideas.cma.job.JobTaskService.getJobTaskList(JobTaskService.groovy:43)
    at com.ideas.cma.reports.TaskStatusController$_closure4.doCall(TaskStatusController.groovy:116)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

I am using jbossall-client.jar which includes this class on the same exact classpath.
If have tried to check and add and test every dependency i cloud find but no luck.

I think its due to some dependency issue but dont know what.

Also tries grails dependency-report but this does not show for the jar added from a lib folder.

Using:
grails 4.0.8 with gradle build.
Using Jboss dependencies to deploy on wildlfy 11.
Windows 10
Also using spring and hibernate in project